# Server always sending data as an escaped character string

Tags: python, json, flask

I have this code and whether I `return jsonify(quote)` or just `return quote` it still ends up as an escaped string on the Javascript front end. `json.dumps()` doesn't seem to do anything either. I'm a js dev... dunno why such a simple thing is so involved in Python. What is the solution for this?

```py
@app.route('/dev/api/stock/price/<symbol>', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin(origin='*')
def get_stock_price(symbol):
    quote = si.get_quote_table(symbol)
    quote['price'] = si.get_live_price(symbol)

    print(quote)

    return quote
```

The print output of the quote is

```
{'1y Target Est': 700.3, '52 Week Range': '379.11 - 900.40', 'Ask': '849.30 x 900', 'Avg. Volume': 18457193.0, 'Beta (5Y Monthly)': 1.89, 'Bid': '849.00 x 800', "Day's Range": '822.35 - 843.21', 'EPS (TTM)': 1.9, 'Earnings Date': 'Oct 20, 2021', 'Ex-Dividend Date': nan, 'Forward Dividend & Yield': 'N/A (N/A)', 'Market Cap': '844.522B', 'Open': 823.74, 'PE Ratio (TTM)': 444.4, 'Previous Close': 818.32, 'Quote Price': 843.030029296875, 'Volume': 18924617.0, 'price': 843.030029296875}
```

On clientside it is received like this

```
data: "{\"1y Target Est\": 700.3, \"52 Week Range\": \"379.11 - 900.40\", \"Ask\": \"849.30 x 900\", \"Avg. Volume\": 18457193.0, \"Beta (5Y Monthly)\": 1.89, \"Bid\": \"849.00 x 800\", \"Day's Range\": \"822.35 - 843.21\", \"EPS (TTM)\": 1.9, \"Earnings Date\": \"Oct 20, 2021\", \"Ex-Dividend Date\": NaN, \"Forward Dividend & Yield\": \"N/A (N/A)\", \"Market Cap\": \"844.522B\", \"Open\": 823.74, \"PE Ratio (TTM)\": 444.4, \"Previous Close\": 818.32, \"Quote Price\": 843.030029296875, \"Volume\": 18924617.0, \"price\": 843.030029296875}"
```

Comment: This looks like a problem with the representation of the data. How do you print it on the client side?

Comment: Forget the client for a second. What does the browser output look like? What about curl?

Comment: Also, unclear what `si.get_quote_table()` actually returns. Is this a dict, or some other class? Printing or returning doesn't tell us this.... If you really are a JS dev, then maybe switch to Express or NextJS?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I will come back and update the outputs... However to the thought of doing it in JS... This is a quantitative finance application I'm building... Essentially a derivatives automation platform so the backend HAS to be in Python. JS does not have equivalent packages for the use case.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there wasn't some obscure NPM module that does financial calculations. Sure, JS doesn't have Pandas, but that doesn't mean it can't do  everything else. `finance.js` can lookup ticker symbols and return JS objects fine on its own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was I forgot I had an axios transform happening on the clientside which I believe was the primary driver of the issue. Also some data formatting was added to the backend.

```js
 try {
    // const response = await api.post(path, obj, { transformResponse: [] });
    const response = await api.post(path, obj); // Correct
    return response;
  }
```

the backend was changed to this

```py
@app.route("/dev/api/stock/price/<symbol>", methods=["GET"])
@cross_origin(origin="*")
def get_stock_price(symbol):
    quote = si.get_quote_table(symbol)
    obj = {}

    for key in quote:
        _key = key.replace(" ", "_")
        obj[_key] = (
            "" if type(quote[key]) is float and math.isnan(quote[key]) else quote[key]
        )
    return jsonify(obj)
```